# How to stop browser from sending additional request on IMG.SRC change in JS

Tags: javascript, html, browser, httprequest

I'm developping an application where images change their source on different user actions. There is about 200 images that can appear this way and I know for sure that at least 90% off them will be displayed at some point.

To prevent flickering I added an image preloader.

However, when I change the SRC attribute of IMG, the browser send a new Get Request, even though the image was already loaded.

According to profiler, such request takes about 30ms on average, and all that happens is that the browser loads the image from cache anyway.

Is there a way to prevent browsers from sending the additional request and displaying the image directly or is that impossible?

If it is impossible, would it be a bad practice to put all 200 images in the code and just switch witch one is visible (or displayed to be more precise)?

How about caching and images as objects in the preloader and only switch them?

Other thing that I was thinking about was to put all those images into a sprite and change only the background position.

What do you think would be the best option?

Comment: Size should definitely matter here, I suppose. ) If your images are tiny, sprite technique is way to go, otherwise I'd use Image objects.

Comment: Are you setting HTTP cache header on the image responses.  Are the GET request returning the full images, or just a 304 Not Modified?

Comment: No, they are returning 200, (from cache), about half of them takes 5ms but the other half takes from 30 up to 80. However, the changes happen as often as every 100ms so 30 - 80ms is just relatively too much.

Answer (score 0):

For the type of fast-paced image swapping that you are describing, I recommend CSS Sprites. If your images are HUGE and your audience could include a fair number of low-speed users, this could be sub-optimal, but you can take some steps to hide that (like first loading a small static image and then swapping it out with the dynamic element after the larger image finishes loading).

Other aspects of the site never got finished, but we employed these type of large scale spriting techniques on http://www.premiumframes.com/ to do layered image switching and to populate the images in the dropdown selectors. Quite a bit of data that loads, but for the audience that can afford their frames, that company was quite happy with the performance. I suspect that your needs wouldn't be as extreme as what that entailed, so you should be able to achieve better performance for the low-to-middle tier of users.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. To be honest, we are not expecting and slow-speed users as the entire site has 20 Megs of images. It is basically more like a movie made in JS and CSS. Our problems are glitches in animation so I'm now trying to find any bits that could be removed and this http request seemed absolutely redundant, or at least i would have thought. It looks to me now that the browser has to complete the request, even to load the image from cache.
I'm now deciding between sprite and switching multiple objects.